# therubyracer incompatible library version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, therubyracer, libv8

My application is running on **ubuntu 16.04** with **ruby 2.1.4p265** and **rails 4.2.2**. I get the following error

```
incompatible library version - /home/aktivlearnadmin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/therubyracer-0.12.2/lib/v8/init.so (LoadError)
/home/aktivlearnadmin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/therubyracer-0.12.2/lib/v8.rb:4:in `require'
/home/aktivlearnadmin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/therubyracer-0.12.2/lib/v8.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
```

This error doesn't happen in ubuntu 14.04. Any solution to fix it?